# IntelliJ using external svn.exe even when option to use command-line client is switched off

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

How do I force IntelliJ to use it's internal SVN library (svnkit?) rather than an external command-line client?  It appears to be ignoring the setting in the options dialog.

Version is 2016.2.4

I had previously been using IntelliJ with the "Use command line client" option switched on.  (Tools...Settings...Version Control....Subversion)

Wanted to check what the performance difference was using the internal SVN support, so I switched the "Use command line client" off, but IntelliJ has just ignored that. It's continuing to use the external svn.exe.

Even if I rename the external client to use it just complains that it can't use the external svn client!

Is something screwed up in the IntelliJ settings files?

Comment: I'd recommend against using SVNKit. Why do you want to switch to SVNKit?

Comment: Because when I start up my project, IntelliJ launches "svn.exe" 146 times (observed with a procmon capture), alternating between "svn info" and "svn status".   That doesn't seem right to me.   Adding more than a handful of files at a time takes an age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I re-read the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-subversion-integration.html) and realised the answer - the built-in IntelliJ SVN support (SVNKit) is only compatible with Subversion 1.7

My working copy format is 1.8, and my SVN server (and local command-line binaries) are 1.9.4, so it looks like I have to use the external command-line.

SVNKit (which is the bundled SVN library) also doesn't look particularly active. The last release (1.8.12) was January 2015.